# Value error i/o operation on closed file python animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, canopy

I am using a standard matplotlib example of animation. The only change i make is to uncomment the save command in order to create an mp4 animation file. The example is :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig2 = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
   ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
                               blit=True)
# To save this second animation with some metadata, use the following command:
im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})

plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error only on my laptop (it works on other computers). I use python Canopy:

```
/home/ubuntu/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.4.3348.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7  /subprocess.pyc in _communicate(self, input)
1406                 # Flush stdio buffer.  This might block, if the user has
1407                 # been writing to .stdin in an uncontrolled fashion.
-> 1408                 self.stdin.flush()
1409                 if not input:
1410                     self.stdin.close()

**ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**
```

Why do i get this error and what can i do?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8053/) suggests that you need to make sure to have ffmpeg available.

Comment: I have ffmpeg and i have set the path in my bashrc file

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386759/animation-funcanimation-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Comment: No for that specific computer it never worked