# Python animation ffmpeg error - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I'm trying to follow this example here to do a simple animation: https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/fsr/rfs07/ELEGANCE/work/code/python/s5p/animation_test.py in <module>()
     25 line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
     26                                    interval=50, blit=True)
---> 27 line_ani.save('lines.mp4', writer=writer)
     28 

     29 fig2 = plt.figure()

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs)
   1061                         # TODO: See if turning off blit is really necessary
   1062                         anim._draw_next_frame(d, blit=False)
-> 1063                     writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
   1064 
   1065         # Reconnect signal for first draw if necessary

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/contextlib.pyc in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     33                 value = type()
     34             try:
---> 35                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
     36                 raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
     37             except StopIteration, exc:

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in saving(self, *args, **kw)
    287             yield self
    288         finally:
--> 289             self.finish()
    290 
    291     def _run(self):

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in finish(self)
    307     def finish(self):
    308         'Finish any processing for writing the movie.'
--> 309         self.cleanup()
    310 
    311     def grab_frame(self, **savefig_kwargs):

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in cleanup(self)
    346     def cleanup(self):
    347         'Clean-up and collect the process used to write the movie file.'
--> 348         out, err = self._proc.communicate()
    349         self._frame_sink().close()
    350         verbose.report('MovieWriter -- '

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.pyc in communicate(self, input, timeout)
    925 
    926         try:
--> 927             stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
    928         finally:
    929             self._communication_started = True

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.pyc in _communicate(self, input, endtime, orig_timeout)
   1711             if _has_poll:
   1712                 stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input, endtime,
-> 1713                                                              orig_timeout)
   1714             else:
   1715                 stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_select(input, endtime,

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.pyc in _communicate_with_poll(self, input, endtime, orig_timeout)
   1767             select_POLLIN_POLLPRI = select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI
   1768             if self.stdout:
-> 1769                 register_and_append(self.stdout, select_POLLIN_POLLPRI)
   1770                 stdout = self._fd2output[self.stdout.fileno()]
   1771             if self.stderr:

/software/local/apps/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.pyc in register_and_append(file_obj, eventmask)
   1746             poller = select.poll()
   1747             def register_and_append(file_obj, eventmask):
-> 1748                 poller.register(file_obj.fileno(), eventmask)
   1749                 self._fd2file[file_obj.fileno()] = file_obj
   1750 

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

ffmpeg on it's own outside of python seems to work ok so I'm not really sure how to get this working?

I've tried using imagemagick as an alternative

e.g.
     line_ani.save('lines.gif', writer='imagemagick')

but this results in the gif jumping around between frames

[image]

Comment: Are you sure to be using the **exact** same code from the example? What versions of libraries, system etc are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386759/animation-funcanimation-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file . Also see this issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8053/

Comment: I'm using the exact same code. I'm working on a cluster which our IT team manage so getting ffmpeg reinstalled might be a pain. the imagemagick issue (the scrolling gif) happens on some of our systems but not on others and no idea why!

Comment: Possibly you do not install ffmpeg, just getting the binary at a location where it can be used may be enough. But obviously I have no idea about this cluster and its limitation. The rolling gif is of course a completely different issue. Again, any info on the systems in use might be helpful here. (Possibly asking two separate questions about those two different issue would make sense.)